# Unable to find component: [mes] using laravel livewire

Tags: laravel-livewire

I have a component using Laravel livewire which disappear please help me how can i resolve that thank u.

please check this error
https://flareapp.io/share/DPyDBeDm

**\app\Http\Livewire\Messaging.php**

```
  public function render()
    {
          
          return view('livewire.messaging');
    }
```

Comment: How are you including it in your blade file? Just showing the above code doesn't provide enough information to provide any kind of help.

Comment: Looks like you are rendering the component like `<livewire:mes />` or `@livewire('mes')`

Comment: You should include component same   <livewire: messaging /> or @livewire('messaging')